# Web dev equivalent of Project Euler

Tags: web-frameworks

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is a site with general algorithmic challenges that can be a part of just about any software but is there any challenges that focus on the overall end result of web apps? It should be compatible with just about any web framework in a similar way that project Euler can be done in any language.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, what you do in a web app, is transform data from one representation to another, pull data from a database and present it in one fashion or another. Accept data from a web page, filter and modify it and plug it back in the database. The number of purely algorithmic challenges as such are very limited (queuing, semaphores and parallelism if things become advanced). I've been doing web apps since 1997, so I'm not downplaying anybody's bread and butter here, as it IS mine .. or maybe I am just a bit jaded ;-)

I simply don't think there are enough general problems, to form the basis of a purely web app challenge site like Project Euler.

The Project Euler problems are very far from anything I have done in my professional career, which (to me) makes them a nice challenge and a great break from the daily routine.

For a non-competitive site that might serve to gather the challenges/task you propose, [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org) could be an answer.